# Strange log message and node not found for anonymous

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a node found at the teaser of front-end for both admin and anonymous users. However, going to the node details page using anonymous user leads to 404 error while it works fine with admin.

The log message details is strange as shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

What is `custom_404_page`? I'm afraid of it is a hacking against the website.

I tried to clear all cache, I disabled XMLsitemap module. I could not able to determine where is the origin of `custom_404_page`.

Also in the log and after clearing it, and the trying to visit this node's details, this is the only log message available. i.e there is no other messages or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Check your custom 404 configuration at `admin/config/system/site-information`.

Also check if this custom configuration is directing users to a Panels page (check `Structure > Panels` or `Structure > Pages` if you have Panels and Page Manager installed). They may be handling different custom 404 pages for different roles. Perhaps the Panel variant that handles the 404 page for anonymous is missing or redirecting to a non-existing page.

Comment: I removed the custom 404 page settings. i.e I have left the input field blank. The idea here the content is really available and appears correctly with admin and other like contents works fine with both admin and anonymous.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying here. Did removing the custom setting fix the problem?

Comment: No it is not fixed.

Comment: OK, then I don't understand what you meant in the comment above.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the content DOES exist, but Drupal is logging a "page not found" report? Is Drupal ALSO showing the "404 Page not found" page when trying to access the content?

Comment: lets we say the problem is related with `node/14148` other nodes of the same type works fine without any problem. This node is not available for anonymous. Anonymous user can only see it as teaser.